# Is it possible to load a XLSX file to be converted into an HTML table, without having a user browse for the said XLSX file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a html page that would load a XLSX file from local directory and then convert it into an HTML table on the same page underneath it, but my current html page requires a user to browse their directory and open said file.

```
<html>
 <input id = "fileUpload" type ="file" > 
 <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()"/>

 <table id="dvExcel"></table>
 <hr>
</html>


<script>
function Upload() {
//Reference the FileUpload element.
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");


//Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        //For Browsers other than IE.
        if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
        } else {
            //For IE Browser.
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = "";
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                    data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }
                ProcessExcel(data);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);

        }
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
} else {
    alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot do that without some sort of browser extension that you'd ask the user to install first.

Comment: You can use SheetJS to parse .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - for security reasons it is not allowed to access local files from web pages without user interaction.

This will only work if you deploy a local application or something similar to the users PC.